# Фиксация изменяющейся переменной класса для цикла python

Tags: python, ооп

Возникла проблема при создании класса: все экземпляры класса должны работать с одним аттрибутом класса:

```py
class xpos:
    position = 0
    def __init__(self, posi):
        xpos.position = posi

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return range(xpos.position)[index]

    def goleft(self, x0=1):
        xpos.position -= x0
```

Также есть два метода класса, изменяющих эту глобальную переменную, и индексирование:

Но если использовать этот массив в цикле, изменяя глобальную переменную, необходимо зафиксировать последнее значение позиции, чтобы пробежаться по всем значениям и не завершить его раньше времени, тем самым при

```py
xx = xpos(15)
yy = xpos(5)  #xpos.position = 5

for i in xx:
    yy.goleft()
```

Ожидаем получить `xpos.position = 0`

*Как этого возможно добиться?*

Comment: честно говоря, ничего не понятно. может вы сделаете код, который можно запустить, и понять, что работает не так, как вам хотелось бы?

Comment: исправил, прошу прощения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А, кажется, понял. Так реализуйте метод `__iter__`, и тогда `for` не будет обращаться к индексации, а возьмёт итератор один раз и ничего не сломается в процессе итерирования:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(range(xpos.position))
```

Я так понимаю, индексация - это запасной метод, если итератор нельзя у объекта взять, тогда для итерирования используется индексация. А в нормальной ситуации берётся итератор и дальше объект уже не дёргается лишний раз, а это как-раз то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Да, не знал про этот "магический метод", начинаю осваивать ООП на Python. Разобрался, большое спасибо!